# .htaccess RewriteRule slash to get parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just transfered my Domain to a new Server. Mod_Rewrite is enabled on the new server but unfortunately some RewriteRules don't work, while others do. I haven't changed anything in the .htaccess

So the URL www.mydomain.com/go/10.html should make an internal redirect to www.mydomain.com/go.php?name=10

The snippet in the .htaccess looks like this:

```
# go.php
RewriteRule ^go$ "$0/" [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^go/$ go.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^go/.*?([^\.\/]*)\.html$ go.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The $_GET["name"] is not available if I call this url.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your .htaccess code with this.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(go)/([^.]+)\.html$ /$1.php?name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```